# How can I get a element in list in R?

Tags: r, list

I am new to R, I want to get a element in a list which is element in another list, like this:

```
> a<-list(foo=1:4,bar=7:9) 
> a 
$foo
[1] 1 2 3 4

$bar 
[1] 7 8 9
```

How can I get the "3" in foo? In python, I use something like

```
a["foo"][1]
```

to get the element, but can anybody tell me the corresponding method in R?

Comment: You've got to double bracket `[[` select first - see the difference between `a["foo"]` and `a[["foo"]]`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `$` to extract the `list` element by names and then subset the value of that element with `[`

```
a$foo[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
a[[1]][[3]]
```

or

```
a[[c(1,3)]]
```

to get element 3 in foo.